# What does SelectObject(dc, hBMP) do?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I guess I do understand what happens if I select "an object" into a "device contect", and if this object is a *brush*, *font*, *pen*: The charactersicts of these objects are hence forth used for the drawing onto the device context.

However, I don't understand what happens after I select a bitmap into the device context, much less, why it is necessary to do so.

I have a program that somehwere does

```
HDC dc = ::GetDC(hWnd);

ffBitmap   = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, windowWidth, windowHeight);
ffMemoryDc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(dc);

hOldBitmap          = (HBITMAP) ::SelectObject(ffMemoryDc, ffBitmap);
```

and later draws unto the *ffMemoryDc* and then *BitBlt*s the ffMemoyDc into the
*real* device context of a window.

```
BitBlt ( dc, 
         0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight,
         ffMemoryDc,
         0, 0,
         SRCCOPY
       );
```

The variable *ffBitmap* is referenced nowhere else in the entire program, yet, if I don't SelectObject(ffBitmap), nothing is drawn, so **it is** necessary.

I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light what happens here.

Comment: Think of it as a rubber stamp.  Created by SelectObject, applied with BitBlt.  The extra indirection is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how it work. The bitmap you select in the DC is the bitmap that is "painted on". Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Before an application can use a memory device context for drawing operations, it must select a bitmap of the correct width and height into the device context.

Comment: Why we can't just create a bitmap with `CreateCompatibleBitmap` and pass `ffMemoryDc` into it as the first parameter?